# fo:change-bar-begin is not a child of fo:inline fop 1.1

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using FOP 1.1 and I am trying to make use of fo:change-bar-begin, but I am getting the following error:

org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:change-bar-begin" is not a valid child of "fo:inline"!

According to W3C Recommandation, change-bar-begin and change-bar-end define "points" and may be used anywhere as a descendant of fo:flow or fo:static-content, basically in any fo:block or fo:inline.

Sample code:

```
<fo:block background-color="Tomato" text-indent="-57.5pt" start-indent="57.5pt">
<fo:inline background-color="aquamarine" font-size="10" font-family="Arial, sans-serif">1.</fo:inline>
<fo:change-bar-begin change-bar-offset="2mm" change-bar-color="red" change-bar-style="solid" change-bar-class="cc01"/>
<fo:inline background-color="LightSteelBlue" keep-with-previous="always" font-size="10" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="48.39pt">Remove panel.</fo:inline>
<fo:change-bar-end change-bar-class="cc01"/>
</fo:block>
```

What do I do wrong?

Thank you!

Florin

Comment: Hi, it seems that (unfortunately) FOP does not support change bars, see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html.

Comment: Waw! I see that FOP 2.0 is in the same situation. Do you know if the current version 2.3 supports change bars, or the 2.0 column refers to all 2.xx versions? What other options do I have with FOP, is there a fairly simple work around?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I had assumed that it had been implemented by now since you were using it.  The not necessarily simple workaround would be to use someone's fork that tries to implement it, e.g.: https://github.com/apache/fop/pull/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks okay to me, and you are correct about `fo:change-bar-begin` being allowed anywhere as a descendant of `fo:flow` or `fo:static-content`.  So this looks like it is a FOP bug.

In your example, `fo:change-bar-begin` is not actually a child of `fo:inline`.  Did you try putting the change bar FOs inside the `fo:inline`?

FWIW, there is a formatted change bar example in the "Comprehensive XSL-FO Tutorials and Samples Collection" at https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/.

Comment: Hi Tony, good catch, thank you. Unfortunately, regardless where you place it, in fo:block or in fo:line, would have the same result.